# Tkinter two "Select All" Checkboxes linked inadvertently

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

hope you can help me with this question. I need to include Select All in my checkboxes. That is working fine, until i created another set of checkboxes. By clicking "Select All" in one checkbox group, "Select All" in another checkbox group is also checked.

Here are my codes so far:

```
#first checkbox group
G1_SUBFRAME = Frame(ENTRY_FRAME)
G1_SUBFRAME.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Label(G1_SUBFRAME, text= "WORKTYPES",
      fg='black', font='none 10 bold', borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20)
G1_A = IntVar()
G1_B = IntVar()
G1_A_BOX = Checkbutton(G1_SUBFRAME, text = "G1_A", variable = G1_A, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 15, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G1_B_BOX = Checkbutton(G1_SUBFRAME, text = "G1_B", variable = G1_B, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 15, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G1_ALL = [G1_A_BOX, G1_B_BOX]
def G1_checkall():
    for element in G1_ALL:
        element.select()
G1_ALL_BOX = Checkbutton(G1_SUBFRAME, text = "SELECT ALL", command=G1_checkall, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 15, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G1_A_BOX.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
G1_B_BOX.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
G1_ALL_BOX.grid(row = 6, column = 2)


#second checkbox group
G2_SUBFRAME = Frame(ENTRY_FRAME)
G2_SUBFRAME.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
Label(G2_SUBFRAME, text= "FILETYPES",
      fg='black', font='none 10 bold', borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20)
G2_A = IntVar()
G2_B = IntVar()
G2_A_BOX = Checkbutton(G2_SUBFRAME, text = "G2_A", variable = G2_A, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 25, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G2_B_BOX = Checkbutton(G2_SUBFRAME, text = "G2_B", G2_B, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 25, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G2_ALL = [G2_A_BOX, G2_B_BOX]
def G2_checkall():
    for element in G2_ALL:
        element.select()
G2_ALL_BOX = Checkbutton(G2_SUBFRAME, text = "SELECT ALL", command=G2_checkall, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 25, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G2_A_BOX.grid(row = 4, column =2)
G2_B_BOX.grid(row = 5, column =2)
G2_ALL_BOX.grid(row = 6, column = 2)
```

Comment: Assign IntVar() to both Select All checkbuttons first.

Comment: ah ok... will try... thanks

Comment: thanks for this. It actually solved the problem. Though a new minor problem emerged. If I uncheck the checked boxes, the "Select All" box is still remained checked.

Comment: Wait, I'm describing the code below.

Comment: If you want to change the check state as Select All buttons try to apply if else conditions inside related functions.For Example,`if G1_ALL_VAR.get()==1:
        for element in G1_ALL:
            element.select()
    else:
        for element in G1_ALL:
            element.deselect()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your question just assign IntVar() to both Select All checkboxes.

If you want to change the check state as Select All buttons try to apply if else conditions inside related functions.

Here's the solution,

```
import tkinter
from tkinter import *

ENTRY_FRAME = Tk()

#first checkbox group
G1_SUBFRAME = Frame(ENTRY_FRAME)
G1_SUBFRAME.grid(row=1, column=0, padx=10, pady=10)
Label(G1_SUBFRAME, text= "WORKTYPES",
      fg='black', font='none 10 bold', borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20)
G1_A = IntVar()
G1_B = IntVar()
G1_A_BOX = Checkbutton(G1_SUBFRAME, text = "G1_A", variable = G1_A, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 15, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G1_B_BOX = Checkbutton(G1_SUBFRAME, text = "G1_B", variable = G1_B, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 15, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G1_ALL = [G1_A_BOX, G1_B_BOX]
G1_ALL_VAR = IntVar()
def G1_checkall():
    if G1_ALL_VAR.get()==1:
        for element in G1_ALL:
            element.select()
    else:
        for element in G1_ALL:
            element.deselect()
G1_ALL_BOX = Checkbutton(G1_SUBFRAME, text = "SELECT ALL",variable = G1_ALL_VAR, command=G1_checkall, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 15, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G1_A_BOX.grid(row = 4, column = 2)
G1_B_BOX.grid(row = 5, column = 2)
G1_ALL_BOX.grid(row = 6, column = 2)


#second checkbox group
G2_SUBFRAME = Frame(ENTRY_FRAME)
G2_SUBFRAME.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=10, pady=10)
Label(G2_SUBFRAME, text= "FILETYPES",
      fg='black', font='none 10 bold', borderwidth=5).grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=20)
G2_A = IntVar()
G2_B = IntVar()
G2_A_BOX = Checkbutton(G2_SUBFRAME, text = "G2_A", variable = G2_A, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 25, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G2_B_BOX = Checkbutton(G2_SUBFRAME, text = "G2_B", variable = G2_B, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 25, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G2_ALL = [G2_A_BOX, G2_B_BOX]
G2_ALL_VAR = IntVar()
def G2_checkall():
    if G2_ALL_VAR.get()==1:
        for element in G2_ALL:
            element.select()
    else:
        for element in G2_ALL:
            element.deselect()
G2_ALL_BOX = Checkbutton(G2_SUBFRAME, text = "SELECT ALL",variable = G2_ALL_VAR, command=G2_checkall, \
                 onvalue = 1, offvalue = 0, height=1, \
                 width = 25, anchor=W, font = "None 10 bold")
G2_A_BOX.grid(row = 4, column =2)
G2_B_BOX.grid(row = 5, column =2)
G2_ALL_BOX.grid(row = 6, column = 2)
```